# Is it possible to measure Earth's rotational acceleration with a home experiment?

Tags: acceleration, earth

Is there an experiment that is achievable using materials you could order online to measure Earth's rotational acceleration at home?

Comment: Foucault's pendulum comes to mind but requires quite a high level of precision engineering. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2019.0680#:~:text=The%20design%20presented%20in%20this,the%20classical%20Earth%20rotation%20problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of centrifugal acceleration (in a reference frame fixed with respect to Earth's surface) would be large enough to measure using a home-made pendulum and other household equipment. At the equator this corresponds to an acceleration of $$a = \omega_E^2 r_E = 0.03 \text{ m.s}^{-2}$$ so pendulums would have period about 0.17% longer than they would otherwise (period $\tau \propto g^{-0.5}$). That would easily be detectable using an ordinary household clock. However, in such an experiment, the change in pendulum period would not be distinguishable from a smaller gravitational field strength. A different experiment, such as a Foucalt's pendulum, would be required to determine which component of acceleration is due to rotation and which is due to gravitation.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're patient and willing to travel, you can use the method of [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) to measure the radius of the Earth $r_E$. The rotational period $T_E$ is obviously about 1 day. Then the rotational acceleration at the equator is

$$
\alpha = \frac{4\pi^2 r_E}{T_E^2}
$$